# How to compile an ASP.NET project without using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net

I'm doing an internship. I have a project to make that needs Visual Studio, ASP.NET and database resources to be done. I have concluded all but the problem is... I need to find a way to **run/build/compile it without visual studio** because it cant be used to profit or in business. I already thought to put it on a server but they asked me if I could find another way. I am searching for an answer for weeks and still not found a way that is "legal" here, in terms of security, and viable.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: Tidied up your post, and removed the company name. Surely a large organisation has licenses for Visual Studio? You could report the lack of a fit-for-purpose development environment to your manager, and report that it's an impediment.

Comment: Thanks for the attention! Yes they do, i have the license for Visual Studio 2013 (other versions would have further expenses for the company) and i can use it to code, but only for code, one of the ideas, i know its kinda stupid but has the obvious solution, was use the Visual Studio to run it full time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Build Tools for Visual Studio” is a free (no restrictions on commercial use) offering from Microsoft that only contains compilers and other stuff required to build various types of applications.

> Supported projects include: ASP.NET, Azure, C++ desktop, ClickOnce, containers, .NET Core, .NET Desktop, Node.js, Office and SharePoint, Python, TypeScript, Unit Tests, UWP, WCF, and Xamarin.

You can find Build Tools on the [Visual Studio download page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), at the bottom in “All Downloads” → “Tools for Visual Studio 2019”. Older versions are also available, in case you need specific C++ versions.

You can then use `MSBuild` on the command line to build your projects.

---

If you need to work with Visual Studio, your company must give a license. Yes, even if you’re just an intern. Build Tools cannot help you modify Database Projects or the like.

IMHO: If the company refuses and you are not required to finish the internship (for school/university or whatever), maybe look for a different internship position elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Daniel! I do have the license, i will try to explain more of the project in between the possible... Basicly they need something automatic that do the update of the information that is presented to the drivers, that information comes from a database, so my ideia is to use ASP.NET and his database resources to do it.

Comment: I need the website or the project to be in a television connected to a computer, but in that computer i dont have and cant install visual studio, because of the terms we cannot use visual studio to run it and show it to the drivers.
So i need to find a way to "publish it" without actually publishing it and to run it in another computer as a "website".
Thanks Daniel!
Sorry but it was to long to be in only one comment..

Comment: Is this not a use case for IoT? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/iot

Comment: @The_Intern You may be misunderstanding; in your question you write “because it cant be used to profit or in business” – this only applies to Visual Studio Community. The “for-money” editions (Professional, Enterprise) can be used in any context. If you happen to be using VS Community right now on company hardware, that’s already against the license terms. // As for the rest (the “what”, not the “how”), that is better suited for Stack Overflow IF you can formulate a single self-contained question in accordance with the site rules.

Comment: @DanielB 
I am using the Visual Studio Professional 2013, that's all "legal". Let me reformulate than... what can i do/use to see my project in other computer without using VS to compile it and not putting it in a server online? Is there any way? Thanks